# Matlab in-place operation A = A + (B*C)

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization, jit, in-place

When memory profiling the following test there is only a (relatively) small allocation (may be buffering results to add full columns) on the line of interest thus I figure this is an in-place operation where each result component of the multiplication is directly added to the corresponding element of the destination matrix A.

```
A = rand(4000);
B = rand(4000,40);
C = rand(40,4000);

A = A + (B*C); % Line of interest

eigs(A,1) % to ensure the computation of A is actually done
```

Yet, in a more complex situation (for example inside a loop with additional operations preceding it) this line creates a full temporary (in the size of A) for

```
B*C
```

I wonder why this is the case. In a large scale setting this may decide on wether Matlab goes Out-Of-Memory or not. May be I am overestimating the JIT and it is not even doing an in-place operation in the test case; or as I hope, there is some trick to push the JIT to act in-place for more complex code, too.

**EDIT**:

Simple Test Case:

[image: Simple Test Case]

Complex Test Case:

[image: Complex Test Case]

(in case you wonder, here: `R` = `N` = 29008)

Complex Code:

[image: Complex Code]

Despite the memory profiler output I can see in `htop` that the memory usage spikes during line 244 by the size of `W` which is about 6GB.

`htop` during line 244:

[image: During line 244]

`htop` after line 244:

[image: Sample for Usage outside line 244]

Comment: You mention two different situations, could you please show the code fragment to reproduce both situations? A hint on how people can see that the temporary matrix is (or isn't) created may help as well.

Comment: As a possible visualization: screenshot of the profiler window.

Comment: This poses a problem as the Matlab memory profiler does not provide useful information for the complex code; I will post screenshots nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `TaskManager` *(i'm working on windows 7)*, i get a memory spike the size of `B*C` with or without `for` loop:

[image: Memory profiling]

```
function [] = toto()
%[
    A = rand(6000);
    B = rand(6000);
    C = rand(6000);

    pause(10);
    %for k = 1:10,
        A = A + (B*C); % Line of interest
    %end
    pause(10);

    eigs(A,1) % to ensure the computation of A is actually done
%]
```

Are you sure that memory profiling with `htop` is accurate enough or that the test is relevant ?

Comment: Neither. Considering your test would then suggest that the memory profiler output for the simple case is already wrong. In this case I will just accept that the this operation is not done in-place.

Comment: Does that not make some kind of sense? The you create a copy, which you can use in the second operation?

Comment: @litro You may temporarly turn off optimizations using `feature('accel', 'off')` to be sure. See this [link](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function)

Comment: The purpose of my question was not a reverse engineering attempt on the JIT functionality but to get an answer from somebody who **knows** if the `A = A + (B*C)` can be done in-place or not.